# Convert C function to Y86 function

Tags: c, assembly, calling-convention, y86

first question here, please let me know if I did anything wrong.

Essentially, I'm having a bit of trouble converting C function to Y86 function. I don't know how to put the C function parameters in registers of Y86 (don't know if I described this correctly but please check my attempt below). Keep in mind I'm relatively new to C and Y86.

Say I have a function in C:

```
quad_t func(quad_t a0, quad_t a1) {
    return ( ( a1 + a0 ) - a1);
}
```

Now I try to put it in Y86:

```
func:
     irmovq 0xa0, %rax
     irmovq 0xa1, %rcx
     addq %rcx, %rax
     subq %rcx, %rax
     ret
```

I assume Y86 took my input literally as 0xa0 (in hex), but I don't know what to do.

Comment: Do you have an Application Binary Interface (ABI) for the Y86 architecture, like the one [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI)?  There are several ways of passing parameters.  The default way is on the stack, so you'll need to pull the data off the stack, do the work, and then possibly clean things up before returning.  If your toolchain supports it, you could compile the C function and see what gets produced as a start (you can use a tool like `objdump -disassemble` to see the instructions generated).

Comment: `irmov` moves as immediate value into a register. Your function's parameters are generally either in registers or on the stack (depending on your calling conventions). One such convention (based on [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI)) would have `a0` in `rdi`, `a1` in `rsi` and your return value in `rax`.

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister: The default / standard calling conventions for x86-64 pass args in registers.  Old 32-bit calling conventions traditionally used the stack, but I wouldn't call that "the default", especially not for 64-bit code like this.  (Note the 64-bit registers and `subq` / `addq` qword operand-size.)  A register-arg calling convention is simpler, especially for tiny functions like this.

Comment: @Haymend: The obvious optimization here is that integer overflow doesn't fault, and addition is commutative, so you can optimize `a1 + a0 - a1` to just `a0`.  No need to do any math, just copy one of the input args to the return value.

Comment: @PeterCordes I realize that.  In this case, I read that Y86 mirrored the IA-32 model, not x86-64.  But it doesn't matter... it's possible the ABI is different and he should follow it. :-)

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister: I think there were 32-bit versions of y86, based on IA-32 without x86-64.  This 64-bit y86 apparently doesn't get called y86-64 so IDK if there's any standard terminology, let alone a standard calling convention.  https://w3.cs.jmu.edu/lam2mo/cs261_2019_08/y86-intro.html says that course is going to use the x86-64 calling convention.  (And also strangely that unlike an earlier y86, this y86 has r8..r14.  No clue why no r15.)  Anyway yes of course they should find out what calling convention they're supposed to use, but I wouldn't say "the default" is on the stack for y86.

Comment: @PeterCordes Sorry I didn't think it through here, the C function was just a made up example by me for simplicity sake, the real assignment question is a little more complicated with more operations. My main concern was trying to get access to the parameters.

Comment: @PeterCordes I see... you're thinking it's 64-bit y86 based on the example assembly he put up.  Fair enough, and on the stack would certainly not be the default in that case and given the confusion around the name, it's definitely fair to say it's not the default.  Thanks Peter!

Comment: @Hasturkun I tried using rdi and rsi and it didn't work. I suppose I would have to look more into the stack stuff. Thank you though.

Comment: @Hasturkun Sorry I messed up, it does work, thank you so much!

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister: Yup, I'd go so far as to say it's "very obviously" 64-bit. Every instruction has a `q` explicit operand-size specifier, and every register name is a 64-bit register.  Even the C uses `quad_t`, clearly a quadword (4x 16-bit x86 "word").  The fact that it was 64-bit was immediate obvious to me in basically the first instant of looking at the code, the same way I could see the text was English on first glance.  I guess I assumed everyone was on the same page with this, but if you were just looking at the "y86" name then that makes sense.

Comment: @PeterCordes I was going off of what y86 was supposed to be (IA-32 in the references I found)  and assuming the rest might be wrong. :-)

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister: most y86 SO questions I've seen have been about the 64-bit version of y86 so I'd seen `irmovq` and so on before.  I'm guessing it's the standard form for teaching now.  Not sure if it's officially called y86-64 but SO only has the one tag, and apparently some sites still call 64-bit y86 by that name, not y86-64.  So the confusion is understandable.